# Nhibernate: Removing child collection with All-Delete-Orphan does not work

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Scenario:

1. Get a FactorDocDTO from UI and assemble to Entity
2. Clear it's child collection FactorDocDetails
3. Updates FactoryDoc

But the child collection wont delete!

FactorDocDetail Map:

```
References(x => x.FactorDoc)
                .Not.Nullable();
```

FactorDoc Map :

```
HasMany(x => x.FactorDocDetails)
                .AsBag()
                .Not.KeyNullable()
                .Inverse()
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Update FactorDoc

```
//Create a new session
FactorDoc doc = _assembler.FromModel(command.FactorDoc);

foreach (var item in doc.FactorDocDetails)
{
     item.FactorDoc = null;
}

doc.FactorDocDetails.Clear();

_repository.Update(doc);

//Flush and commit
```

FactorDocDetails stills in db

Comment: FactorDoc is not nullable. How can you set it to null? Did you already try to just remove the foreach?

Comment: @Stefan I expected nhibernate delete FactorDocDetails because of  doc.FactorDocDetails.Clear(); Also I tried with nullable and without foreach but didn't work

Comment: can you please show Clear() method?

Comment: Also is not necessary to do _repository.Update(doc); commit should be enough.

Comment: @MDDDC Clear() is a CLR method! and doc is a detached entity because it assembled from command so _repository.Update(doc) is necessary!

Comment: ahhhh....detached  entity this is why Clear()  method didn't work like was expected....You should load object from db and after it to do all your changes.and after it commit changes...Take a look at this post : http://blog.miraclespain.com/archive/2007/Sep-20.html and at this one : http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2009/6/11/nhibernate-calling-update-unnecessarily/ .

Answer (score 0):

It took Three days, I tried every possible things and finally it worked!

```
 _repository.Get(command.FactorDoc.Id);
 FactorDoc doc = _assembler.FromModel(command.FactorDoc);
 _repository.Merge(doc);
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you are flushing your session and you should also not need the foreach loop that sets those to null.  Personally instead of flushing the session I prefer to execute the statements within a transaction:

```
using (NHibernate.ISession session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession())
{
    using (NHibernate.ITransaction tran = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        doc.FactorDocDetails.Clear();
        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

It's also difficult to say what your _repository.Update(doc) is actually doing.

Comment: like doc is detached object first you should to load it from db and after it to to Clear() ...

Comment: Not sure why I got a downvote for this.  These are very legitimate reasons why these things could happen.